# Strange grey border around image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, border

on [my site](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/) when you enter the main menu and hover over 'Populaire boeken'. The first 2 menu items are working and on mouseover an image appear. But if you take a good look there is a **grey border** around the image? How do get rit of it? I tried everything. `border:none; border:0; outline:none` etc

The image appear with this jQuery function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.level1 li').mouseover(function(){
                $this = jQuery(this);
                if(typeof $this.find('img').attr('src') != "undefined"){
                    $this.parent().parent().parent().find('.imageChangeDefault').css('background','url('+$this.find('img').attr('src')+')').css('background-repeat','no-repeat').css('width','inherit').css('height','inherit').css('background-size','100% 100%');
                }
            });
        })

    </script>
```

I really don't know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce the code to a [minimum, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), and post that code in your question. Don't expect us to traipse around the internet in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are 2 javascript/jquery errors. That is probaly what the problem is.

But we need code to help you out.

Hope this helped you more.

Comment: i update my question with my jQuery function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see the images but no border around it, except the light grey border that contours around the book.  This is part of the image file.  http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/media//menupro/Image-1415098340.png

Comment: I don't see any border in the image

Comment: @Randy Greencorn the image is a transparent png 24... There is a small grey border around..

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what is causing your issue, I took a look at your site. On your imageBox div, you could set 'overflow: hidden;' and on the img itself, use 'margin: -1px;'

This will help hide your lines, but won't get rid of them. I suspect you might want to do some more snooping and discover the source.